# Other feats that add CHA to saves like Steadfast Personality?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

From the Class Guide, Steadfast Personality allows you to add your CHA to Will saves instead of WIS. Are there other feats that let you add your CHA to your Fortitude or Reflex saves too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I highly recommend [this document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1o91Z-s0R7Vf2Ujj1lFqGC5W--9JOyU0I6uC9XRIR5to/). It is not really up-to-date but it is still useful.

As a feat, there is only [Divine Protection](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/divine-protection/) lets you add your Charisma to one saving throw a day, by an immediate action. It used to be way more powerful but the nerf hammer struck hard.

But there is also this trait: [Irrepressible](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/faith-traits/irrepressible/), (that you can obtain through the Additional Traits feat), which lets you use your Charisma instead of Wisdom for saving throws against charm or compulsion.

Comment: Note that irrepressible is much, much worse than steadfast personality, and does almost nothing that the latter didn't already cover.  This makes sense because it's a trait, but if you already have the feat, it's not gonna do anything for you.  The document is a good document, though.

Comment: It actually can be better than Steadfast if you have less than 10 in Wisdom (since Steadfast makes you keep the Wis penalties but Irrepressible doesn't)

Answer (score 4):

## Yes.

You can cover all saving throws with Charisma.

[Kobold Confidence](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/racial-feats/kobold-confidence/) allows you to add your Charisma to Fortitude Saves instead, and the Lore Oracle revelation [Sidestep Secret](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/mysteries/paizo-oracle-mysteries/lore/) allows you to Charisma to Reflex Saves instead.

Comment: If you don't wish to be a Kobold, you can take Racial Heritage (Kobold) if you are human.